# What is the minimum graphics card requirements for Wp 7 emulator?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have a core2duo desktop computer with 256 mb of graphics card & 2GHz cpu. But wp7 emulator is not running when I start debugging my application. Kindly tell me what are the emulator's graphics card requirements except of those mention on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

*ALL* the requirements of the emulator are specified on MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524(v=vs.92).aspx

If you think your machiine meets all the requirements but it's still not working it may be a driver issue or your processor may not support HAV.